# swift: Is correct to use stored properties as computed properties

Tags: ios, swift

I'm try to achieve this objective-c code

```
@property (strong) UIView *customView;

-(UIView*)customView
{
   if (!customView){
       self.customView = [[UIView alloc]init];
       self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  }
   return customView;
}
```

Why am I use this? customView called from many place, so we have to check this condition in all place. To avoid this duplication, I wrote this.

So I'm try to create stored properties and also use getter method to check if already either created or not.

```
var mainView : UIView? {

  get{
   if let customView = self.mainView{
        return self.mainView
   }
   var customView : UIView = UIView() 
   self.mainView = customView
   self.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor(blueColor)
   return customView 
 }
 set{
  self.mainView = newValue
  }
}
```

Is this correct? or any other approach to do this?

**Note:** There's no warning or error with above code. But confusion with stored and computed properties. Please make me clear.

Comment: http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure why, but lazy variables combined with computed properties result in an error:

```
'lazy' attribute may not be used on a computed property
```

But this seems to work:

```
class MyClass {
  @lazy var customView: NSView = {
    let view = NSView()
    // customize view
    return view
  }()
}
```

Comment: I guess computed properties are lazy by their nature. They get computed when they're accessed and not before.

Comment: This is a nice solution to being able to do some complex initialisation in a lazy stored property. It's essentially calling a closure (() -> NSView)() to do the initialisation rather than a initialiser directly eg. NSView().

Comment: It's working great :). accept this answer now. If I get better answer, i'll update.:)

Comment: @MikePollard although a computed property is computed when it's accessed, it's not memoized, i.e., its return value isn't saved. Therefore, a computed property is computed *every time* it's accessed. I wouldn't call that lazy. :-) A lazy stored property, on the other hand, is only computed the first time it's accessed because it's memoized, and therefore, every subsequent access just returns the saved value.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a lazy property. Just declare it like any other stored property but with the `@lazy` modifier. The object will be created when somebody first tries to get it. You don't need to write that stuff for yourself.

See 'Lazy Stored Properties' in [the Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html). You'd just write:

```
@lazy var customView = UIView()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do addition calculation? like set backgroundcolor...?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent should be the following in swift 2.1:

```
var _customView:UIView? = nil
var customView:UIView {
    if _customView == nil
    {
        _customView = UIView.init()
        _customView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
    return _customView!
}
```

---

Also, I will write your original objective-C code as the following so as to avoid calling the getter of `customView` multiple times:

```
@property (strong) UIView *customView;

// @synthesize customView; // make sure you didn't add this line

- (UIView*)customView
{
   if (!_customView){
       _customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
       _customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   }
   return customView;
}
```